# what is the difference between garbage collector and traditional memory collector?

Tags: memory-leaks, garbage-collection, garbage

difference between garbage collection and traditional memory collector?

Which applications do not work well with garbage collector?

Comment: What is a “traditional memory collector”? It seems you want to refer to something *without* a collector. Since you are likely referring to manual memory management, the term “traditional” doesn’t fit either. Garbage collection is much older than you think and manual memory management is still in use.

Answer (score 1):

Garbage collection is a way of managing memory (or even other resources like file descriptors on Linux, or [inodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) in a file system, or maybe some kind of temporary tables used in some SQL service).

In my opinion, traditional memory management (think of C++ constructors/destructors) is a limited form of garbage collection.

Read the [GC handbook](https://gchandbook.org/) for more.

> Which applications do not work well with garbage collector?

Those consuming many dynamic resources (e.g. window widgets, file descriptors, [agents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent-oriented_programming), perhaps sub-proofs in some automatic proof assistant, [OpenCL kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) ....) that are not well managed by *your* GC.

Hence, GC algorithms are useful to know even when coding in a language or implementation (Ocaml, Scheme, Common Lisp) having a GC for memory. If you code a video game, you many need to implement some kind of specialized GC for sprites, etc... (even if your game is coded in on the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine), which requires a GC for memory).

My opinion is that GC algorithms, terminology or heuristics are useful in *many* occasions (for example, even [git](https://git-scm.com/) has some "GC").